# JS onclick doesn't work with external js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to perform onclick on a text in a external js file.
This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="p">
      Use the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element:
    </p>
    <p class="demo">Click me to change the above text</p>
    <script>
      window.onload = startListen();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My js file

```
function startListen() {
  var demoElement = document.querySelector(".demo");
  var pElement = document.querySelector(".p");
  demoElement.onclick = function change() {
    pElement.innerHTML = "Text is changed";
  };
}
```

I want to click p.demo and the text in p.p will be changed but not working with external file. It still works with inline syntax with html attribute like this.

html

```
<p class="demo" onclick="change()">Click me to change the above text</p>
```

js

```
function change() {
  var pElement = document.querySelector(".p");
  pElement.innerHTML = "Text is changed";
}
```

I added onload but not work. Could u help me! Thanks

Comment: load the 1.js file before the `window.onload` statement.

Comment: oh it is solved, thanks so much buddy

Answer (score 0):

For connect external js file use  <\script>.

Then ni need to use script tag in the html script.
Then simply use the onlclick in the html with a name then use the name in the js file using then the name you use in the onclick.

Comment: U mean onclick inline html tag like this <p class="demo" onclick="change()">Click me to change the above text</p>

Comment: Yes, you are right. amazing. Go ahead.